# In Flutter what is a SpinEdit called?

Tags: flutter

There is the UI component in Delphi, called a "SpinEdit", and in QT its called a "SpinBox".

Is there something in Flutter that can replicate this? Below is a picture of what the component looks like, it allows the user to select a numeric value by incrementing +1 when the up arrow is clicked, and the decrement -1 when the down arrow is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Flutter, there is a similar widget called NumberPicker. It provides a spinning wheel interface for selecting numeric values. However, the NumberPicker widget is not available by default in the Flutter SDK, so you'll need to use a third-party package to add this functionality to your Flutter project.

One popular package that provides a NumberPicker widget is the flutter_numberpicker package. You can add it to your pubspec.yaml file and import it in your Dart code to use the NumberPicker widget.

https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker